# How to evaluate the wiener measure of sets?

Tags: pr.probability, mp.mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics

I would like to understand how the Wiener measure of some simple sets can be evaluated. 
I will sketch the construction of Wiener measure I have in mind:

We denote the one point compactification of $\mathbb{R}^n$ by $\hat{\mathbb{R}}^n$. Now consider the product space $$\Omega:=\prod\limits_{0\leq t<\infty}\hat{\mathbb{R}}^n.$$ By Tychonoff's theorem this space is a compact and hausdorff space. Now the idea is to construct the wiener measure with the aid of riesz representation theorem. 
Consider first functions like this $\varphi:\Omega\rightarrow \mathbb{R}, \varphi(w)=F(w(t_1),...,w(t_n))$ with $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $t_1<t_2<...<t_n$ and some continuous F. Now define the following linear functional on all those functions given by:

$$\Lambda(\varphi)=\int....\int p(t_1,x,x_1)p(t_2-t_1,x_1,x_2)...\times p(t_n-t_{n-1},x_{n-1},x_n) F(x_1,...,x_n)dx_1....dx_n,$$

where $p(t,x,y)$ denotes the heat kernel on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

The space of all such $\varphi$ is dense in $C(\Omega)$ and therefore we can extend $\Lambda$ continuously on the whole space $C(\Omega)$. By Riesz representation theorem there exists a regular Borel measure $\mu$, s.t. for all continuous functions $f$ we have:

$$\Lambda(f)=\int f d\mu$$.

This measure is called Wiener measure.

Now I want to understand how to calculate measures like $\mu(G)$, whereas $G:= \lbrace{ w:[0,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n \vert \omega(t)\in U\rbrace}$ with fixed $U\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ open. The problem is that the characteristic function $1_{\lbrace{ w(t)\in G , 0\leq t<\infty\rbrace}}$ is not continuous, therefore I can't calculate it like $\Lambda(1_{{\lbrace{ w(t)\in G , 0\leq t<\infty\rbrace}}})$

I would really appreciate any help!

Comment: The usual construction goes via Kolmogorov's extension theorem, followed by Kolmogorov's continuity test. This gives you a Borel measure on the space of continuous functions. The set $\{w\,:\, w(t) \in G\,\forall t\}$ is a perfectly nice Borel set there. In order for it to have non-zero measure, you will need $n \ge 3$ and $G$ unbounded.

Comment: There is something wrong with the definition, as $ w (t) $ cannot belong to a set of $ w $'s.

Comment: I don't think you are really asking the right question here.  Asking "In general, how do I compute the Wiener measure of sets" is tantamount to asking "In general, how do I prove theorems about Brownian motion."  It is a very large theory and there are a great variety of techniques.  Some very deep and difficult theorems (as well as open questions) can be stated as asking for the Wiener measure of a particular easily-described Borel set.  So if there's a *specific* set whose measure you want to know, you should ask that by itself.

Comment: @Martin Hairer: Thank you very much for your comment. I will consider the construction via Kolmogorov soon. But I'm not a probabilist.

Comment: @Kjos-Hanssen: Why do you mean the set can't be a Borel set?

Comment: @Nate Eldredge: I want to know the measure of the set G (which I wrote down above), which is quite explicit. Don"t you think so?

Comment: @supersnail: Perhaps you should rephrase your question, then, to focus on the specific problem that interests you (in particular the title is misleading).  But the necessary techniques will depend on what $G$ is.  For example, if $G = \mathbb{R}^n - \{p\}$, you are asking about the recurrence and transience of Brownian motion, and that's already a nontrivial fact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let $t$ be fixed and look at the set $\{ w \mid w(t) \in U\}$. Take a sequence of continuous functions $f_k$ that are uniformly bounded and converge to the indicator function of a set $U$ in the Borel-Algebra of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $\pi_t$ be the projection on the $t$-th component of Omega.  Then
$$\int_\Omega (\pi_t)^*f_k d \mu = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} p(t, x, y) f_k(y) d y$$
by construction. Because the $f_k$ are bounded and the measure is finite, they are dominated by an integrable function and by Lebesgue's theorem on bounded convergence,
$$\mu(\{w(t) \in U\}) = \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}\int_\Omega (\pi_t)^*f_k d \mu = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} p(t, x, y) \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} f_k(y) d y = \int_{U} p(t, x, y)  d y $$
Hence non-continuity is no real problem.

To now tackle your problem, notice that the indicator functions of the cylinder sets
$$ G_{N} := \{ w \mid w(k/N) \in U \forall k = 1, \dots, N^2 \}$$
converges a.s. to the indicator function of $G := \{ w \mid w(t) \in U \forall t \geq 0 \}$ as $N \longrightarrow \infty$: Clearly $G \subset G_N$. On the other hand, if $w \notin A$, then $w(q) \notin U$ for some rational number $q$ and therefore $w \notin G_N$ for $N$ big enough.

The dominated convergence theorem gives then
$$ \mu(G) = \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \int_U \dots \int_U \left(\prod_{k=1}^{N^2} p(1/N, x_{k-1}, x_k) \right) d x_1 \dots d x_{N^2}$$
If this is helpful at all, I cannot say.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I have to think some time about your approach and probably will tell you whether it helps.

Answer (score 1):

The probability $h(x,t)$ that the Brownian motion path started from $x$ stays in a given set $U$ for $0<s<t$ satisfies the heat equation: $\Delta_x h-\partial_t h=0$ with initial data $1$ and boundary data zero. The large $t$ asymptotics is governed by the leading eigenvalue of the Laplacian and by projection of the constant function $1$ to the line spanned by the leading eigenfunction.